# How do I get the filtered gallery to work using the nested list?

Tags: javascript, css, filter, nested-lists, image-gallery

I've got wanted to categorize the images/projects into 4 categories:all,urbanism,acrhitecture, and interior design.Then when you click on the subcategories but it's also filtered and when you click on a subcategory it filters the images. However, something is wrong and the inner filter is not working at all.I tried the following, I expected it to be like  a nested filter but it still didnnt work. It didnt show anything even whenn i tried to put the classes of the subcategories.I want the nested filter to work without affecting the css. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>AAC - Projects</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="apple-touch-icon"
      sizes="180x180"
      href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="16x16"
      href="images/favicon-16x16.png"
    />
    <link rel="manifest" href="images/site.webmanifest" />
    <link href="styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/miragestylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/projects.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <img
            class="logo"
            src="images/aac BLACK GREY 2023.png"
            alt=""
            srcset=""
            style="width: 120px; height: 120px"
          />
        </a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"
          data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar"
          aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar"
        >
          <div class="hamburger">
            <div class="top-bun"></div>
            <div class="meat"></div>
            <div class="bottom-bun"></div>
          </div>
        </button>
        <div
          class="offcanvas offcanvas-end"
          tabindex="-1"
          id="offcanvasNavbar"
          aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel"
        >
          <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn-close"
              data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
              aria-label="Close"
            ></button>
          </div>
          <div class="offcanvas-body">
            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html"
                  >Home</a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="news.html">News</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="career.html">Career</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="futiristic.html">Futiristic</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="about_section">
      <br />
      <h1>projects</h1>

      <ul class="switcher">
        <li data-cat=".all" class="active">All</li>
        <li data-cat=".urb" id="show">
          Urbanism
          <ul class="switcher" id="content" style="display: none">
            <li data-cat=".cityscale">City Scale</li>
            <li data-cat=".residential">Residential</li>
            <li data-cat=".entertainment">Entertainment</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-cat=".arch" id="showarch">
          Architecture
          <ul class="switcher" id="contentarch" style="display: none">
            <li data-cat=".adminstrative">Adminstrative</li>
            <li data-cat=".commercial">Commercial</li>
            <li data-cat=".hospitality">Hospitality</li>
            <li data-cat=".residential">Residential</li>
            <li data-cat=".educational">Educational</li>
            <li data-cat=".cultural">Cultural</li>
            <li data-cat=".entertainment">Entertainment</li>
            <li data-cat=".medical">Medical</li>
            <li data-cat=".religious">Religious</li>
            <li data-cat=".restoration">Restoration</li>
            <li data-cat=".infrastructure">Infrastructure</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-cat=".int" id="showint">
          Interior Design
          <ul class="switcher" id="contentint" style="display: none">
            <li data-cat=".residential">Residential</li>
            <li data-cat=".commercial">Commercial</li>
            <li data-cat=".cultural">Cultural</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="container large">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a href="index.html"
          ><img
            class="all urb residential"
            src="images/1.jpg"
            alt="Sample photo"
        /></a>
        <a href="index.html"
          ><img
            class="all urb entertainment"
            src="images/1.jpg"
            alt="Sample photo"
        /></a>
        <a href="index.html"
          ><img
            class="all urb cityscale"
            src="images/12pp.jpg"
            alt="Sample photo"
        /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      <main class="grid">
        <a href="index.html"
          ><img class="all urb cityscale" src="images/1.jpg" alt="Sample photo"
        /></a>
        <a href="index.html"
          ><img
            class="all urb residential"
            src="images/low-angle-greyscale-building-with-modern-brutalist-architecture-sunlight.jpg"
            alt="Sample photo"
        /></a>
        <a href="index.html"
          ><img
            class="all urb entertainment"
            src="images/1.jpg"
            alt="Sample photo"
        /></a>
        <a href="index.html"
          ><img
            class="all arch"
            src="images/low-angle-greyscale-building-with-modern-brutalist-architecture-sunlight.jpg"
            alt="Sample photo"
        /></a>
      </main>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <a
            class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-floating m-1"
            href="https://wa.me/+201111007091?text=urlencodedtext"
            role="button"
            ><i class="fab fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i
          ></a>

          <a
            class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-floating m-1"
            href="https://www.instagram.com/aac.consultant/"
            role="button"
            ><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i
          ></a>

          <!-- Linkedin -->
          <a
            class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-floating m-1"
            href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/arab-american-consultants/about/?viewAsMember=true"
            role="button"
            ><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i
          ></a>
          <!-- Behance -->
          <a
            class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-floating m-1"
            href="https://www.behance.net/60fd0eab"
            role="button"
            ><i class="fa-brands fa-behance"></i
          ></a>

          <!-- Pinterest-->
          <a
            class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-floating m-1"
            href="https://www.pinterest.com/ArabAmericanConsultants/"
            role="button"
            ><i class="fa-brands fa-pinterest"></i
          ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="font-family: 'made_miragethin'">
          © 2023 Arab American Consultants . All Rights Reserved.
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="projects.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
let switcherLi = document.querySelectorAll(".switcher li");
let imgs = Array.from(document.images);

switcherLi.forEach((li) => {
  li.addEventListener("click", removeActive);
  li.addEventListener("click", filter);
});

function removeActive() {
  switcherLi.forEach((li) => {
    li.classList.remove("active");
    this.classList.add("active");
  });
}

function filter() {
  imgs.forEach((img) => {
    if (!img.classList.contains("logo")) {
      img.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
  document.querySelectorAll(this.dataset.cat).forEach((el) => {
    el.style.display = "block";
  });
}

var urbanismElement = document.getElementById("show");
var contentElement = document.getElementById("content");

urbanismElement.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target === urbanismElement) {
    if (contentElement.style.display === "none") {
      contentElement.style.display = "block";
      archcontent.style.display = "none"; // Hide architecture subcategories
      intcontent.style.display = "none"; // Hide interior design subcategories
    } else {
      contentElement.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};

var archelement = document.getElementById("showarch");
var archcontent = document.getElementById("contentarch");

archelement.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target === archelement) {
    if (archcontent.style.display === "none") {
      archcontent.style.display = "block";
      contentElement.style.display = "none"; // Hide urbanism subcategories
      intcontent.style.display = "none"; // Hide interior design subcategories
    } else {
      archcontent.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};

var intelement = document.getElementById("showint");
var intcontent = document.getElementById("contentint");

intelement.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target === intelement) {
    if (intcontent.style.display === "none") {
      intcontent.style.display = "block";
      contentElement.style.display = "none"; // Hide urbanism subcategories
      archcontent.style.display = "none"; // Hide architecture subcategories
    } else {
      intcontent.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};

var allElement = document.querySelector('.switcher li[data-cat=".all"]');
var categoryElements = document.querySelectorAll(".switcher li[data-cat]");

allElement.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target === allElement) {
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryElements.length; i++) {
      categoryElements[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    allElement.classList.add("active");
    contentElement.style.display = "none";
    archcontent.style.display = "none";
    intcontent.style.display = "none";
  }
};
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Advent+Pro&family=Amatic+SC&family=Bricolage+Grotesque:opsz@10..48&family=Cardo&family=Comfortaa:wght@300&family=Domine&family=Gruppo&family=Indie+Flower&family=Kodchasan:wght@300;500&family=Lato&family=Oswald&family=Playfair+Display+SC&family=Playfair+Display:wght@500&family=Roboto:wght@100&family=Rubik:ital,wght@1,300&family=Syncopate:wght@400;700&family=Urbanist&display=swap");

* {
  font-family: "laluxesserifw05-regularRg";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "MADEMirage-Thin";
  src: url("MADEMirage-Thin.ttf.woff") format("woff"),
    url("MADEMirage-Thin.ttf.svg#MADEMirage-Thin") format("svg"),
    url("MADEMirage-Thin.ttf.eot"),
    url("MADEMirage-Thin.ttf.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
p {
  font-family: "made_miragethin";
}
section {
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
.container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
}
.navbar-brand {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar-nav {
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 0.5 1em;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: Regular;
}
.about_section {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.about_section h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery {
  --s: 150px; /* control the size */
  --g: 10px; /* control the gap */
  --f: 1.5; /* control the scale factor */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  gap: var(--g);
  width: calc(7 * var(--s) + 6 * var(--g));
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}
.gallery > a {
  display: contents;
}
.gallery img {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: grayscale(80%);
  transition: 0.35s linear;
}

.gallery img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  width: calc(var(--s) * var(--f));
  height: calc(var(--s) * var(--f));
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  div.large {
    display: none;
  }
}

/***** for mobiles *****/

@media (min-width: 699px) {
  .cont {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 699px) {
  div.small {
    display: none;
  }
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.grid img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}
.grid div {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.switcher {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: fit-content;
  align-items: stretch;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 90vw;
}

.switcher li {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
  font-size: 12px;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;

  cursor: pointer;
}

.content div {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.switcher .switcher {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 90vw;
  left: 0;
}

.switcher ul li ul {
  list-style-type: circle;
}

/* .navbar*/

.hamburger {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger div {
  align-self: flex-end;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
.hamburger .meat {
  width: 70%;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger .bottom-bun {
  width: 90%;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger:hover div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
.hamburger:hover .top-bun {
  animation: burger-hover 1s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
}
.hamburger:hover .meat {
  animation: burger-hover 1s infinite ease-in-out alternate forwards 200ms;
}
.hamburger:hover .bottom-bun {
  animation: burger-hover 1s infinite ease-in-out alternate forwards 400ms;
}
@keyframes burger-hover {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.navbar-toggler,
.navbar-toggler:focus,
.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler-icon:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.switcher {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: fit-content;
  align-items: stretch;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 90vw;
}

.switcher li {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
  font-size: 12px;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;

  cursor: pointer;
}

.content div {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.switcher .switcher {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 90vw;
  left: 0;
}
```